# Windows Batch commands to copy file to multiple subdirectories

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, file-transfer

I have 2 files *file1.txt* and *file2.txt* that I want to copy into a folder structure like this

```
parentfolder
    subfolder1
         destinationfolder
    subfolder2
         destinationfolder
    subfolder3
         destinationfolder
    subfolder4
         destinationfolder
    subfolder5
         destinationfolder
```

where file1.txt and file2.txt go into the destinationfolder directory. Also the names of the *subfolder(NUM)* are unique and nonsequential.

Is there a way to automate this copy and paste task?

Comment: Do all destinationfolders have the same name?

Comment: Yes, the destinationfolders are all the same name, just the subfolder names are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the folders are unique and non-sequential, I will assume you know in advance what they are.

You can use xcopy for this or robocopy

This is with xcopy

```
xcopy "c:\myfile.txt" "c:\parent\subfolder1\" /z /i
xcopy "c:\myfile.txt" "c:\parent\subfolder2\" /z /i 
xcopy "c:\myfile.txt" "c:\parent\subfolder3\" /z /i
xcopy "c:\myfile.txt" "c:\parent\subfolder4\" /z /i
xcopy "c:\myfile.txt" "c:\parent\subfolder5\" /z /i

xcopy "c:\myfile2.txt" "c:\parent\subfolder1\" /z /i
xcopy "c:\myfile2.txt" "c:\parent\subfolder2\" /z /i
xcopy "c:\myfile2.txt" "c:\parent\subfolder3\" /z /i
xcopy "c:\myfile2.txt" "c:\parent\subfolder4\" /z /i
xcopy "c:\myfile2.txt" "c:\parent\subfolder5\" /z /i
```

Save the code to notepad, and save as. Name it Copy.bat (note the .bat), Run it. All done.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
Looks like I will have to hardcode the subfolder names in the script. Is there not a way to use wildcards to indicate the subfolder name?
The subfolder names are like "abc" , "xyz" , "ohi" , etc.

Comment: No, you can't do that but there are some work arounds - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609028/copying-files-with-wildcards-in-the-path

Answer (score 2):

This batch file should take care of your requirement once you edit the paths and folder names properly:

```
@echo off
for /r "drive:\path\to\parentfolder" %%d in (.) do (
    if "%%~nd"=="destinationfolder" (
        xcopy "drive:\path\to\file 1.txt" "%%~d"
        xcopy "drive:\path\to\file 2.txt" "%%~d"
    )
)
```

Comment: Is the "%%~nd" supposed to mean if any directory inside parentfolder has a destinationfolder directory?

Does the ~ indicate to go 1 level deeper into the directory?

Comment: "Is the "%%~nd" supposed to mean if any directory inside parentfolder has a destinationfolder directory?" - Yes. "Does the ~ indicate to go 1 level deeper into the directory?" - No, it just removes the quotes. See `for /?` for more. Why do you ask? Do you have other subfolders of parentfolder that also have destinationfolder inside but where you do *not* want the files to be copied?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here, Karan gave a good answer, thanks! For me what I needed was to remove this part

```
if "%%~nd"=="destinationfolder"
```

for it to work for me. The If statement as stated on the last reply seeks specific folders if you put on the "destinationfolder", removing this line will target all folders inside the parent folder, which is what I wanted in my case.